# ¿Qué convención de nombrado debo utilizar en bases de datos?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Me gustaría saber que convención para nombrar tablas resulta más apropiada y por que.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yo te puedo comentar lo que yo uso. No he visto ninguna regla que indique que tiene que ser de tal manera.... o de otra...

- Por supuesto siempre en **inglés**.
- Nombres de las **tablas** siempre **MAYÚSCULAS** y en **plural**.
- Nombres de los **campos** siempre **minúscula** y en **singular**.

El motivo de la **Mayúscula** y la **minúscula** es para **identificar** rápidamente en una SQL cual es la **tabla** y cual es el **campo** que se referencia. En las select con múltiples JOINs creo que se ve claramente que no es mala idea usarlo así.

El motivo de **plural** o **singular**. ¿Las tablas almacenan múltiples registros de `User` o **`Users`**? Queda mejor para mí **Users**
y ¿cada registro tiene **`name`** o `names`? Pues creo que es más apropiado decir **name**. A no ser que el campo sea una *key foránea* entonces lo apropiado es usar pequeños identificadores que visualmente te ayuden a identificar que ese campo que tiene algo más que un dato simplón. Por ejemplo la tabla **`COMMENTS`** tendrá un campo **`user_id`** (no `users` ni `id_usuario`, ni cosas raras). Referencia de forma singular a la tabla foránea `USERS` e indica que ahí almacenas el ID, **`user_id`**

En las tablas intermedias, por ejemplo cualquier relación *one to many* como, por ejemplo, `usuarios` (`USERS`) y todas las fotos subidas (`PHOTOS`). Respeto las **MAYÚSCULAS** y uso el símbolo **`_`** para concatenar **`USERS_PHOTOS`**.

En algunos casos en los nombres de las tablas o de los campos se suele usar un prefijo para identificar el proyecto o el servicio del que proviene o de donde se va hacer uso esa información. En el caso de las tablas no me gusta usar prefijos, pero en los campos sí (`siebel_id`, `joomla_id`, `twitter_token`...)

De todas formas, no hay normas establecidas sobre esto. Por eso me he topado con cosas como la tabla **`Población`**, o tablas relacionadas como **`Población?Ciudad`** o mejor aun **`Códigos postales`**. Creo que para no hacer daño a nadie, mejor evitar acentos y para caracteres de concatenación *"raros"* como el espacio en blanco, `?`, `-`, `+`, ...

Comment: Muy buena respuesta de hecho, un método que sin darme cuenta también utilizo.

Comment: Partiendo de que es una pregunta basada en opinión, y son solo convenciones, diré que no estoy de acuerdo en lo de poner en nombre de las tablas en plural. Creo que es mejor ponerlas siempre en singular ya que representan una entidad y llevado al modelo relacional se entiende mejor una relación con entidades en singular. Al igual que cuando las tablas representan objetos llevado a la programación orientada a objetos lo normal es llamar a la clase en singular.

Answer (score 2):

Para mi uno de los maestros en Sql Server es phinal Dave, tiene un documento detallado de estos estándares es http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/06/sql-server-database-coding-standards-and-guidelines-complete-list-download/

Answer (score 1):

Esto es un tema relativo ya que como en los lenguajes de programación, la respuesta no es única y cada quien podría preferir una convenio u otra.

En mi caso para indistintamente del motor de base de datos, utilizo en **plural** los nombres de tablas, y en **singular** los nombres de las columnas, en ambos casos usando **PascalCase**. Si queda a mi elección, los nombres en ingles y utilizar únicamente un campo para la llave primaria al cual siempre llama `Id` de tipo numérico o UUID(dependiendo si la tabla utiliza borrado lógico o es de muy alta concurrencia).

Las llaves foraneas llevan el nombre de la tabla seguido de Id, para cuando son una única relación(Ejemplo `DetallesFactura` y `Facturas`). Si posee mas de una relación(Ejemplo `Facturas` y `Usuarios` `UsuarioCreaId`, `UsuarioAnulaId`), coloco el nombre de la tabla, una o dos palabras para denotar la diferencia en el campo con otro del mismo tipo de relacion.

En **SqlServer** la mayoría de los objetos aceptan nombre de hasta 128 por lo que, nunca he tenido problemas con estas características.

En el caso de **Oracle**, las cosas cambian un poco, el máximo permitido es de 30 caracteres, y aunque se puede usar nombre en minúscula, la costumbre es que todo este en mayúscula, por lo que separamos las palabras con  `_` y se utilizan acronimos o abreviaturas en las tablas de relacion muchos a muchos, o con nombres compuestos.

Otra consideración, y probablemente la razón por la que SQLServer uso esta forma es que por lo general utilizo un ORM para el accesos a base de datos, por lo que el código generado mantiene el estilo que utilizamos en `C#`.

Como ves es una cuestión de estilo. [Aquí](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)) encontraras un poco mas de detalle de Convenciones de Nombres utilizadas en lenguajes de programación. Tambien en SO [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338156/table-naming-dilemma-singular-vs-plural-names) que incluye explicaciones muy interesantes.